# BING search API suddenly returns "401 PermissionDenied"

Tags: bing-api

I'm doing some light testing of the Bing search API using the Azure free tier. I've only used it a handful of times.

Now, suddenly, search requests return a "401 PermissionDenied", without anything having changed on my end.

I follow the example that's [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-web-search/quickstarts/rest/php), with the only change being that I use my keys.

Oddly, when I look at the metrics over at the API console, it seems to tell me I have made no calls, ever, which is not correct.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regenerating my keys magically worked. :/